# TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON when sending array via express

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I have a few different files which contain multiple functions that are related, I'm using them as controllers of sorts. In one I have a promise and am hitting my catch block when trying to resolve it. It is done in a bit of a different way than passing a single value like I most commonly see. I am trying to resolve with a JavaScript object which contains two keys, one with a value of a boolean and the other with an array for a value.

The actual error I am getting in my catch block is

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Here is how I am trying to resolve the promise

```
resolve({success: true, names: body.names});
```

Where `body.names` equals the below array

```
[ [ 'John Smith', 'Jane Doe' ], [ 'John Smith' ] ]
```

My goal is to have the promise resolve in a way that I can pass my 'success' value to do some extra processing (not an error if false and needs to be handled as a non error) but would also like to be passing the array of names so that I can pass that on in my API response.

EDIT**

More code

```
exports.formatWithNames = function(policy) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        options.json = {policy};
        request.post('/userListByIDs', options, (err, response, body) => {
            if (err) {
                logger.error(`policy: formatWithNames: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
                reject({success: false, message: 'Failure'});
            }
            logger.info(`policy: formatWithNames: body: ${JSON.stringify(body)}`);
            resolve({success: true, names: body.names});
        });
    });
}
```

Then where that is called

```
Policy.find({ companyID: req.body.user.companyID }, (err, policy) => {
        if (err) {
            logger.info(`getAllPolicy: Policy find: Error message: ${err}`);
            return res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Error finding policies.' });
        }

        userController.formatWithNames(policy)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            return res.status(200).json({ success: true, policy: res });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            logger.error(`getAllPolicy: formatWithNames: Error message: ${err}`);
            return res.json({ success: false, policy: null });
        })


    });
```

Comment: Nothing in the code shown in your question could produce that error. Please provide more details, in particular a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Phil What kind of things would produce the error? I included what I thought was producing it. Not sure what else to post

Comment: @Phil added all possible code that could be related

Comment: looks like you do `policy: res` ... and JSON stringifying `res` will cause that error ... did you mean `policy: response`? oops - see you answered yourself for a simple typo

Comment: @Bravo Bingo, and that simple typo had my head spinning around for a few nights now wondering what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Okay solution was stupidly simple and was just me having a variable miss named, feeling pretty low right now. I should have used `policy: response` instead of `policy: res` when returning my response in my then block of the formatWithNames. So what seems to have been happening was `res` was being sent back but because I was including it in the response it was creating a circular reference to itself (looping?)